# What is this purple dried flower?

Tags: identification, flowers

My friends have these flowers on their kitchen windowsill and they have been there in not too much direct sun for at least a year now. Does anyone know what flower this is? The purple has stayed around for a long time.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like Statice and yes, it does last a very long time dried!